# How to redirect with htaccess to https while adding a language paramterer

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, get

I have two domains example.com and example.de. Bot are pointing to the same server with the same website.
If somebody is opening the site he should be redirected to use https://example.com regardless of the queried domain.

Until now I'm using the following htacces code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

But now I want that everybody who was initially querying example.com is "redirected" to use the language parameter `?l=2` and everybode who opened example.de to use `?l=1`.

It would be great if anybody knows how to combine that with https.

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ https://example.com/$1?l=1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ https://example.de/$1?l=2 [R=301,NE,L]
```